# CORS error in API Request from Chrome Extension despite URL in Manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cors

I am writing a Google Chrome extension that makes requests to an API. I ran into this error about a week ago and was able to solve that issue by adding the relevant URLs to the host_permissions in the manifest.json. However, I ran into this issue again. The URLS are already added to the manifest.json and I don't think this is server side since my extension worked previously and I have not made any changes to the server. [Picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n4Lc.png)

I have added the following URLs to the manifest: [URLS in Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lemdw.png)

Aside from this, I do not know what else to do.

Comment: If this is inside the content script, see [this answer](/a/55292071).